# Problem with g++ in Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: compiling, g++

i'm trying to compiling this class:

--> This is the Vector3D.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <math.h>

class Vector3D{
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
public:
    Vector3D() : x(0),y(0),z(0){}// Default constructor
    Vector3D(float ix,float iy,float iz);
};
```

--> This is the Vector3D.cpp:

```
#include "Vector3D.h"

Vector3D::Vector3D(float ix,float iy,float iz){
    x=ix;
    y=iy;
    z=iz;
}
```

To compile the class i use this command:

```
g++ Vector3D.cpp Vector3D.h -o prueba
```

And the error that i obtained is the next:

```
Vector3D.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In the _start function:
(.text+0x20): reference to main undefined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could somebody say me, how i can resolve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI I ran the non-english error messages through a translator for our English speaking people, and applied correct code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included the header file in the compilation command. Use the following command:

```
g++ Vector3D.cpp -o prueba
```

This command will remove the warning for pragma. However, your CPP file does not contain any main function. So, g++ can not create an executable.

You can change the file to:

```
#include "Vector3D.h"

Vector3D::Vector3D(float ix,float iy,float iz){
    x=ix;
    y=iy;
    z=iz;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to add a main function in the source code, then you can compile it just to create an object file by adding a `-c` switch like this:

```
g++ Vector3D.cpp -c -o prueba
```

Comment: I just tried that option and I get the same error. Trhanks

Comment: > `(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main'` <-- I think you're misisng a "main" function in your application, C++ applications need a `main` entry point.

Comment: Hah I was already writing an answer when you edited it in xD

Comment: @cavero00 Then we either need your complete code or more information.  As it currently stands the errors you're getting are because you're trying to compile incomplete code.  Chances are you're looking for the "object file" compiler format to include it elsewhere later, so the `-c` flag in the `g++` call might help you.  I recommend though that you also pay attention to `-Wall` and get any deprecation or code warnings for potential bad practices when you compile, too, but that's my opinion.

Comment: With the answer of one is enought. It work perfectly. i only need the vector3D.o. Thank you.